# print from commandline using dll printHTML - printer selection

Tags: vbscript

I can print a txt file from command line using the following code:

```
rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSHTML.dll, PrintHTML "C:\Test.txt"
```

but every time a window pop up and ask me which printer to use... 
I've read some threads about the possibility to do something like this:

```
rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSHTML.dll, PrintHTML "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"
```

where %2 is the printer name.

I tried this

```
rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSHTML.dll, PrintHTML "c:\test.txt" "<printername>"
```

but had no luck.

Any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per below link it seems that for security reasons automatically running above command has been blocked.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/02/24/printing-documents-to-microsoft-xps-document-writer-without-user-interaction.aspx

Line from above blog:

*"So you should be able to print any webpage to any printing device, to any printer/file, fully automatically. But this creates a security risk, so it has since been blocked. User confirmation is needed to print an HTML page through MSHTML.DLL."*

**Alternatively**, as you are printing a text file you can use below command to print a text file from command prompt:

```
start /min notepad /P <filename>
```

Comment: I've already tried with notepad, but the problem is that a window appears (title: NOTEPAD) and tell "document is now printing". This window automatically disappear when printing is done. I didn't find any way to avoid this window appear. Any suggestion?